# AlpacaJS: Toggling Form view from edit to view and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just starting to use AlpacaJS.  One of the things I'd like to do is to load a form and then switch between edit and view only mode, i.e. via a button click event for example.

AlpacaJS allows me to load the form in one of these 2 mode during initialization of the form but doesn't seem to provide any API to do it after.  In fact, if anything, looking at the docs, it doesn't seem to provide APIs to do anything after the form is initialized... am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the View Selector example:
http://www.alpacajs.org/demos/bootstrap/clubs/index.html